# 'Could Not Find Your Craft/ Folder' After Updating

Tags: updating

I updated to the latest version of Craft, and I am getting this error:

> Could not find your craft/ folder. Please ensure that $craftPath is set correctly in /storage/xxxxxxx/www/public_html/index.php

I have updated the same way each time. This is the first time I am seeing this error.

The files are setup like this:

Server

- www/

  - craft/
  - public_html/

    - index.php

This is what the index.php file has always been:

https://cl.ly/281K2H3a3r1y

Permissions are the same as the previous app folder: 775

Any ideas about what may be causing this? As I said, I have updated Craft several times before without any problems. I've also read other threads on this and didn't find a solution that works for me. I am wondering why this would be a problem now, when it hasn't been an issue during previous Craft updates?

Thank you for any help you can give!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the permissions have been 774, not 775 as mentioned in my post. I think that was messed up somehow during the upload, and I missed that it wasn't the correct setting. I had also cleared my firewall cache earlier and it hadn't worked. When I cleared again just now after resetting permissions, everything seems ok.